# How the use decode option of protoc for decoding google::protobuf:any types

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, decode, protoc

I try to decode a binary file which inherits some serialized proto3 messages. I do this with protoc and the option `--decode`.

All work fine until one of the serialized messages contains a google::protobuf::Any field. This field contains another message which is defined in a extra `.proto` file. When i execute the `--decode` option of the protoc then the `type_url` is correct and a value with the raw bytes is shown.

Is it possible that the protoc is able to detect which message is included in the Any field and decode it corresponding to the `.proto` file of this message? If yes, how can i do this?

Thanks in advance!